# ExecuteNonQuery() fails to operate

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, database-connection, windows

Simple `INSERT INTO` a SQL Server using a C# application. Have debugged successfully down to the line

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The program doesn't err or break, but nothing happens. I've explored the possibility of a dev/production database hiccup, but that does not seem to be it.

The code below is the Save button click. The names of database objects and connection parameters `DataSource` `Table` `Catalog` etc. are generalized, not verbatim.

```
string val1 = firstTextBox.Text;
string val2 = secondTextBox.Text;
string val3 = thirdTextBox.Text;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DataSource;Initial Catalog=Catalog;User ID=username;Password=password");
string sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Table(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (" + val1 + "," + val2 + "," + val3 + "); ";

try
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
{
    string msg = "Insert Error:";
    msg += ex.Message;
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Besides your problem, have you considered fixing the huge SQL injection vulnerability present in your code?

Comment: Trace your application and show us what the string `sql` gets set to.

Comment: Please add _int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()_ and tell us the value of rowsAffected.

Comment: Maybe the text in thirdTextBox is `');rollback transaction--`

Comment: @RobertColumbia `sql` is dandy.  Returns the string that works great in SQL Server Mgmt Studio!
@Steve Added it along with `MessageBox.Show("rA"+rowsAffected);` on the line after.  Program never gets here that I can tell.  No message box, that's for sure.

Comment: "_that i can tell_" Have you actually used the debugger to step line by line? If not, your `catch` block isn't going to show you anything.

Comment: Try to remove all the exception handlers you have around this code. If there is an exception you should be able to see it and understand a lot more about the problem

Comment: @Steve Roger that, will do and get back with any results

Answer (score 0):

**If your code was copied and pasted verbatim**, your connection string is not valid.

`Data Source=DataSource;Initial Catalog=Catalog;User ID=username;Password=password`

You need to fill in the proper values for the `DataSource`, `InitialCatalog`, `UserID`, and `Password` values.

Also the query itself would be wrong unless you actually have a table named `Table`.

As an aside, you also should look into (Google search for) parameterized SQL queries, as well as `using` statements for proper disposal of resources (a.k.a. classes that implement `IDisposable`).

Comment: If this was the problem then an exception would be raised and the OP says NO ERRORS

Comment: I suppose it's *possible* the name of the Data Source is `datasource`, etc.. OP is unclear about a number of things.

Comment: @Steve He's eating any `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` errors...so of course the app doesn't crash.

Comment: probably not smart to post your actual user id and password to stack overflow

Comment: _Have debugged successfully down to the line "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"_ however it is true that the wording is unclear.

Comment: @JamieD77 Nor was I suggesting he post them, but given all the values in that connection string, it leads me to believe his code was copy and pasted verbatim.

Comment: @Sylverac  that means you're also assuming he has a table named Table and 3 colums col1, col2, col3?  Possible.. but i'd like to believe it was scrubbed before posting

Comment: @JamieD77 I've edited my answer to reflect that assumption as well. I can't really help any more without the OP answering some of the questions raised in these comments.

Comment: @Sylverac Please see the edits made to the post (proper values for connection and "Table" are int the real code, just not pasted here).  Any suggestions for a `using` statement?